# React textarea callback when losing focus / onBlur

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom-events

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-textarea-callback-on-blur-yoh8n?file=/src/App.tsx

Having a textarea in React I want to achieve two basic use cases:

1. Remove focus and reset some state when the user presses "Escape"
2. Execute a callback (`saveToDatabase`) when the user clicks outside of the textarea and it loses focus (=> `onBlur`)

```
<textarea
  ref={areaRef}
  value={input}
  onChange={handleChange}
  onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
  onBlur={handleBlur}
/>
```

For the first use case I'm calling `blur()` on the target:

```
const handleKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
  if (e.key === "Escape") {
    console.log("Escape clicked");
    setInput(inputForReset);
    e.currentTarget.blur();
  }
};
```

..but this also calls the `onBlur` handler, which I actually want to utilize for the second use case. I tried to determine if the event caller is the textarea itself via a ref, but that doesn't work:

```
const handleBlur = (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
  console.log("blur");
  /**
   * Only save to database when losing focus through clicking
   * outside of the text area, not for every blur event.
   */
  if (areaRef.current && !areaRef.current.contains(e.currentTarget as Node)) {
    saveToDatabase();
  }
};
```

In other words: I want to save something to a database when the user is finished editing at the textarea, but I don't know how to distinguish between the `blur` event I triggered programmatically and the native `blur` event that the textarea uses when you click outside of the node.

Comment: Instead of calling the blur event you can focus it anywhere else, maybe on the parent or anywhere

Comment: @Sim I don't think so, because focusing some other node will natively call the `onBlur` handler of the textarea when it was focused before:  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-textarea-callback-on-blur-forked-2butt?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed what the error is.
The target of the blur event is itself

```
areaRef === event.target
```

So you have to implement an additional function to catch click outside the box.

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

function useOutsideAlerter(
  ref: React.RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement>,
  fun: () => void
) {
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleClickOutside(event: any) {
      if (
        ref.current &&
        !ref.current.contains(event.target) &&
        // THIS IS IMPORTANT TO CHECK
        document.activeElement === ref.current
      ) {
        fun();
      }
    }

    // Bind the event listener
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      // Unbind the event listener on clean up
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [ref]);
}

export default function App() {
  const areaRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);
  const [inputForReset, setInputForReset] = useState<string>("Original input");
  const [input, setInput] = useState<string>(inputForReset);

  const saveToDatabase = () => {
    console.log("save to database");
    setInputForReset(input);
    alert(input);
  };

  // OUT SIDE CLICK

  useOutsideAlerter(areaRef, saveToDatabase);

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    if (e.key === "Escape") {
      console.log("Escape clicked");
      setInput(inputForReset);
      e.currentTarget.blur();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  };

  // it doesnt work
  
  const handleBlur = (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    /**
     * Only save to database when losing focus through clicking
     * outside of the text area, not for every blur event.
     */
    console.log(event.target);
    console.log(areaRef);

    if (areaRef.current && !areaRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
      saveToDatabase();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <textarea
        ref={areaRef}
        value={input}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        className="area"
      />
      <p>Input state: {input}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please check my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-textarea-callback-on-blur-forked-4vtd3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: `document.activeElement === ref.current` was the missing piece!  I already had the same implementation to check the outside click, but I didn't know how to NOT execute the callback when you click somewhere else randomly.

Comment: For future readers: Here is the complete version:   https://codesandbox.io/s/react-textarea-callback-on-blur-geo3w

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a variable (or a class property, if you are using class component instead of a functional one) as a "preventsaveOnBlur" flag; something like:

```
let preventSaveOnBlur: boolean = false;

const handleKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
  if (e.key === "Escape") {
    console.log("Escape clicked");
    setInput(inputForReset);
    preventSaveOnBlur = true;  // will prevent saving on DB - see handleBlur 
    e.currentTarget.blur();
  }
};

const handleBlur = (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
  console.log("blur");
  /**
   * Only save to database when losing focus through clicking
   * outside of the text area, not for every blur event.
   */
  if (!preventSaveOnBlur) {
    saveToDatabase();
  }
};

const handleFocus = (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
  preventSaveOnBlur = false;
};
```

and in the textarea you handle the onFocus event too:

```
<textarea
  ref={areaRef}
  value={input}
  onChange={handleChange}
  onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
  onBlur={handleBlur}
  onFocus={handleFocus} // will reset 'preventSaveOnBlur' to false every time the textarea get the focus
/>
```